# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-redux, react-hooks

> Movie.js

This is my React Component throwing error of map property Cannot read. it just happen when I refresh page, means at first render, however when I comment & uncomment map function it get proper results and render my data to DOM, if refresh page it shows error I think My DOM render before getting data. Also used axios but same results. I struggling with it from 4 days. Thank You

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
// import axios from "axios";
// import Datacard from './Datacard';

function Movie (){
    const [movieData, setmovieData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        getdata2()
    },[]);
    function getdata2(){
        fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/day?api_key=91d216ec6cb5cb93f831efa4ca831725')
        .then(async(res) => await res.json())
        .then((data)=>{setmovieData(data.results);console.log(data.results)})
    }
    return(<>
            <div>
                <p>safsdfasdfd</p>
                {movieData.map(value=>(<div>{value.title}</div>))} //if I just comment & uncomment this part I get proper results, but when I refresh page I get error  
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default Movie;
```

> index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.scss';
import Movie from './Movie';
// import App from './App';`

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Movie/>
  </BrowserRouter>
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> console error

```
Movie.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at Movie (Movie.js:17)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21881)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482)
    at react-dom.development.js:26021
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:22431)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26020)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:8)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (index.scss?7975:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: why don't you initialize movieData with an empty array instead?

Comment: `map()` is a prototype function for arrays in javascript. `map()` will throw an error if it's not chained to an array. It's throwing the error because you lose the data when you refresh. Apply a condition like this `{movieData?.length && movieData.map(value=>(<div>{value.title}</div>))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix: You need to set initial value in `useState`. Instead `null` set empty array (`[]`), cause [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is function for arrays.

```
const [movieData, setmovieData] = useState([]);
```

Or check for null with `movieData?`

```
 {movieData?.map(value=>(<div>{value.title}</div>))}
```

Or

```
{movieData === null
      ? "Loading..."
      : movieData.map(....)}
```

Theory: Please take a look the image below. There is the lifecycle of react components.
[image]
--- Mounting // first column

1. Mount the component `Movie`
2. Initialize movieData with `null`
3. Execute `useEffect` but this is async function
4. Render the return - ERROR appear here. You just pass `null` for `movieData` and you cannot perform `.map` on `null` it looks like `null.map(....)`

---Updating // the second column

1. When you get result from fetch, React automatically perform update and re-render component again with array `[mov1, mov2, mov3]` then you can perform `.map()` funciton

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the movieData as null.
So that error occur.
Please initialized that movie Data as empty array.

```
const [movieData, setmovieData] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When the component first renders, the value of `movieData` is `null`.

You should either initialise `movieData` with an empty array, or conditionally render the content based on whether `movieData` is truthy (not null).